Accessing JavaScript chrome.debugger / chrome.tabs from extension
I am trying to access the chrome developer API from JavaScript inside an extension.
The problem is that the properties chrome.debugger or chrome.tabs are undefined (not part of the "chrome" object).
My manifest looks like this:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "MyExtension",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "BackgroundWorker.js" ],
    "type": "module"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "open_in_tab": true
  },
  "permissions": [ "storage", "scripting", "tabs", "debugger", "activeTab" ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      ...
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "framework/*",
        "content/*",
        "app.js"
      ],

      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
    }
  ]
}

The Chrome DevTools output from console.log(chrome):

As far as I know, my manifest file has the right permissions, so why can I not access the debugger/tabs properties?

Content scripts can't use these APIs. You can use them in the background script or the popup/options page.
